# Excel 2010/2013 line chart

Tags: excel, charts, excel-2010, line, excel-2013

I haven't had to use Excel graphs for more than 10 years... and find myself needing to create a simple chart with a series of lines.

Each line will start at (0,0), and then move to the (x,y) points specified.

For example

```
X,Y
20,5000
25,7500
40,9000
```

This should have three lines.  All of them start at (0,0), and move to the points specified.  Ideally, I'd like to be able to specify the max ranges, and have the lines start from (0,0) and keep going until they hit the boundaries.

This should be really simple to do, but I can't recall how, and all my Google search results are assuming I want to do something far more complex.

Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to do a bit more processing on your data to get the result you want but I believe it is doable fairly simply

First, identify your maximum X value (in my example I have chosen 20000 (cell (A2))

Then list out the X and Y values for the Series, with their origins (0,0) and their values as listed in your table above (Cells A4 through F5)

[image]

You can then copy the maximum value into Row 6 in cells A6, C6, E6 to make the next bit easier to understand.

Then you can use the [TREND](http://www.excelfunctions.net/Excel-Trend-Function.html) function to extrapolate from your known data (rows 4, 5) up to your maximum value (row 6)

For Series 1 for example the expression

```
(Cell B6)   =TREND(B$4:B$5, A$4:A$5, A$6, FALSE)
```

Says, for Y-values B4 and B5, I know the corresponding X-values A4 and A5, so if I also have A6 as the maximum X-value, what would the Y value be?  (the False just says the equation must go through the origin)

You now have a table that looks like this

[image]

Create a new “Scatter With Straight Lines and Markers” chart and add three data series.  Series1 would look like this

[image]

Once all three series have been added you now have a chart that shows the lines up to your maximum value for the ratios you have defined above.

[image]

Hopefully this is helpful.  Let me know if I can be of further assistance.